# Где была создана база данных по умолчанию?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

В EF Core стандартным способом: Add-Migration + Update-Database, была создана база данных Sql Server. Она была создана со строкой соединения

```
@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Integrated Security=True"
```

То есть без указания `Initial Catalog`.

С ней можно работать, даннные вставляются/удаляются/изменяются/получаются.

Но где находится сам файл mdf?

В папке пользователя его нет. В папке приложения - нет. В папках самого Sql Server - нет. Поиск по *всему* диску ничего не нашёл. Мистика!

Причём команда Drop-Database не работает: выдаёт сообщение, что в строке соединения должен быть указан `Initial Catalog`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оказалось, что без указания `Initial Catalog`, таблицы контекста были добавлены в системную БД master. Что, конечно же, нехорошо. Не следует таблицам пользователя быть в системной БД.

---

База была пересоздана с указанием каталога. Ставшие ненужными таблицы удалены вручную.